# Documentlistener not listening automatically in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

I got the listener to work, but I have to click "ENTER" on the keyboard for the document listener to start working. How do I get it to listen without having to click enter.

```
private void pool_sizetextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    size = pool_sizetext.getText();
    s = Integer.parseInt(size);
    pool_sizetext.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
{

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
       get();
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
      get();
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
       get();
    }

    private void get()
    {
        size = pool_sizetext.getText();
        s = Integer.parseInt(size);
    }
});
}                                             

private void monthly_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
cal();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
" Weekly Amount: "+s+ " \n\n Monthly Amount: "+w+ " \n\n Yearly Amount: "+yearly+ "",
"Results",
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

Remember that this is using "Swing" GUI Panels.

Thanks for a Response.

Comment: For better help sooner, please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are adding the listener inside the `pool_sizetextActionPerformed`, that's why you have to click Enter to trigger the method. Try moving the code that adds `DocumentListener` into the constructor of the panel.

Comment: @Genzer I put the code in a Componentadd Listener and nothing happend, then I put it into a Keylistener and so far it works, but is this the right way? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: `but is this the right way?` - No. You add the DocumentListener to the text component when you create the text component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for a working example.

Comment: @camickr It works for only one of my DocListeners the other one just doesnt do anything. Simmilar code for both `private void weekly_visittextComponentAdded(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {                                                
        weekly_visittext.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
{
@Override
public void changedUp.... 
{
getw();
}
 @Override
public void insertUp.... 
{
getw();
 }
@Override
  public void removeUp.... 
 {
 getw();
        }
private void getw()
{   
week = weekly_visittext.getText();
w = Integer.parseInt(week);  
}     
});      
}`

Comment: `It works for only one of my DocListeners` - so you've proven it works. `Simmilar code for both` - so compare the working code with the code that is not working to see what is different. This is a basic debugging skill. Don't post code in a comment. Why are you adding the DocumentListener in a ComponentAddListener (whatever that is)? The suggestion was to add the DocumentListener when you create the text component. Post a proper [SSCCE]() if you need more help.

Comment: Im using Swing GUI in Netbeans and the ComponentAddListener is found in the properties of the Textfield. So I dont create a text component.

Comment: And there is no difference besides the variable names.